# Tecnologías arm, i386 o ch64 móviles con javascript

Tags: javascript, android

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo tres versiones de instalador de **firefox** para **android** , la `57.0.1-i386`, `57.0.1-arm` y `57.0.1-ch64`, tengo un sitio donde detecto que el navegador sea **firefox** y si es menor a estas versiones, propongo actualizar. Como con `javascript` puedo saber la tecnología del móvil para cuando descargue el instalador sea la de la tecnología que utiliza ese dispositivo?

PD: no tengo código echo por eso no les muestro nada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Como con `javascript` puedo saber la tecnología del móvil para cuando descargue el instalador sea la de la tecnología que utiliza ese dispositivo?

Para detectar la arquitectura del navegador debes utilizar [`navigator.platform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/platform)

```js
console.log(navigator.platform);
```

En **Firefox Mobile para Android** los valores pueden ser, por ejemplo: `Linux i686` o `Linux armv7l`

Comment: Incluso esto puede funcionar dentro de un WebView no únicamente en el navegador del dispositivo.

Answer (score 0):

Para complementar la respuesta de Marcos, esto puede funcionar incluso en un Android `WebView`, para esto agregamos:

```
console.log(navigator.platform);
```

o un alert

```
alert(navigator.platform);
```

Es indispensable habilitar la ejecución de `JavaScript` y además configurar un `WebChromeClient` para obtener la información  de la arquitectura:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);        
    webView.loadUrl(< url de página web >);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```